# attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, null

This is part of my game.lua I keep getting this error though.

```
function scene:createScene(event)

end

screenGroup = self.view

background = display.newImage("Space-Background-Image.gif")
screenGroup:insert(background)

local background1 = display.newImage("Space-Background-Image.gif")
background.x = 90
screenGroup:insert(background1)


function scrollBackground(self,event)
if self.x < -480 then   
    self.x = 480
else
    self.x = self.x - 3
end
end
```

Comment: The Lua interpreter should tell you what line number the attempt occurs? If so, please point to it in the code (via a label like *** or a comment).

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to call functions in lua

1) call the function with ':' gives 'm' as first argument
`m:DoJob()`

2) but if you call if with '.' you have to define the context where to look for the function, typically the module itself
`m.DoJob(m)`

If you call a method defined in the module as `module:Method()` with `module.Method()` it expects as argument self and throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to me that you've misplaced the closing `end` in your `createScene` method. Try moving the lines below into the function body so the implicit `self` is used instead of the global `self` key:

```
function scene:createScene(event)
  screenGroup = self.view

  background = display.newImage("Space-Background-Image.gif")
  screenGroup:insert(background)

  local background1 = display.newImage("Space-Background-Image.gif")
  background.x = 90
  screenGroup:insert(background1)
end
```