# Search Results lua - Attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm running this code in hopes to make my enemies spawn constantly every 5 seconds but I just keep getting "Attempt to index global 'self' (a nil value)." This is in my game file and the table is from my enemy file. Any help is appreciated.

```
timer = timer + dt
if timer >= 5 then 
table.insert(self.enemies, enemy)
timer = timer - 5
end
```

Comment: I don't do Lua so don't expect much, but have you tried `table:insert(self:enemies, enemy)`? I got this from [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20258484/attempt-to-index-global-self-a-nil-value)

Comment: If `enemies` is global variable, then try `table.insert(enemies, enemy)`

Answer (score 2):

`self` is valid inside functions where `self` is an explicitly specified parameter or a function is defined using the colon operator (as in `function foo:bar()`), as it will be provided as a hidden parameter in this case.

It seems like in your case, none of these two cases is satisfied and `self` is taken as an undefined global variable.

See [Object-Oriented Programming chapter in Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) for details and examples of proper usage.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any solution or another way to make my enemies spawn constantly?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong that I can see. I will explain one correct way to do it, and you can compare it to the way you have it set up.

In your enemy file (I'm going to assume its called enemy.lua), there should be a table that contain a couple of things:

1. A table that will contain your list of enemies (make sure to return it at the end of the file!)
2. A function that creates a new enemy

It could look something like this:

```
local enemies = { }    -- table to export

enemies.list = { }     -- list of entities

function enemies.new()
    local new_entity = { }

    new_entity.x = 0        -- set entity coordinates
    new_entity.y = 0        

    -- set any another entity information, like sprites, health, etc.

    return new_entity
end

return enemies         -- make this table available to other files through require
```

Then, you import it into main.lua with this line:

```
local enemies = require "enemies"
```

That will make `enemies.list` and `enemies.new` available inside your main.lua. Your table.insert then becomes

```
table.insert(enemies.list, enemies.new())
```

---

Basically, your main mistake was trying to access something inside another file without using `require`. Hope this helps.